# Data Studio line chart baseline average

Tags: looker-studio

In Data Studio I want to create a line chart that shows two lines.  The first line is the average quantity from the previous year.  This is a single value calculated from last year's data that shows as a horizontal line.  The second line displays the running daily quantity for the current year.  My data source is BigQuery

I have the second line plotted with date as the dimension and current year's daily quantity as the metric.

I don't know how to plot the first line - the single number average from the previous year.

I tried creating a second data source for the average through a view and BigQuery Connector Custom Query.  I am unable to link the second data source through the date dimension because it is a single value

How do I plot the average?

Answer (score 0):

I instead added a running average by:

- I Added the quantity again as a second metric with a "Sum" aggregation
- In the editor of this new metric under "Apply Running Calculation" I selected "Running Average"

This at least gives me some type of baseline for comparison of current quantity.